# How to create a new table based on combination of two cells based on a third?

Tags: r, excel

I have a field called "Conferences" and a second one called "Members". Each Conference has several Members who participate in this event. What I want to do is extract a table just with the binary relationship of "members" who participate in the same Conference.

Lets say we have "UN Conference 1945" with participants John, Jack, Jamie and Pablo. The table would have to give me:

```
John, Jack
John, Jamie
John, Pablo
Jack, Jamie
Jack, Pablo
Jamie, Pablo
```

Comment: Not at all clear in fact, as your example resembles no logic (to me anyway)? Perhaps try rephrase.

Comment: So what you want is, all the k-combinations (with k=2) of  participants of each conference (without repetitions and no matter of the order (for a mathematical point of view of this sort of set see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination))?!

Comment: Yes. I am only interested in one pair for each conference, no matter the order. Some website, like http://mergewords.com/ can do this, but they generate both john-jack and jack-john. And I am interested in having only one pair.

Comment: If your data is stored in a database, then it would probably the best if you use the data base to solve this issue (If you have lots of data). I can also think of an Solution using the Python plugin in SPSS but I need some time to work this though. I think it's pretty easy to do, in R or in Python directly (without SPSS). Do you have one of these installed on your computer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might not asked for a solution in R, but using SPSS for this problem would be quite painfull (if possible at all).

Let's assume you have a csv-file (Conference-Participants.csv) which looks like this:

```
Conference,Participant
UN Conference 1945,John
UN Conference 1945,Jack
UN Conference 1945,Jamie
UN Conference 1945,Pablo
UN Conference Kyoto 1997,Ben
UN Conference Kyoto 1997,Katie
UN Conference Kyoto 1997,Julie
```

In R you could solve your puzzle the following way.

```
library(data.table)
library(combinat) # you probably have to install this package first

# read csv-file
df <- read.csv("Conference-Participants.csv")

# split the data by conferences
subs <- split(df, df$Conference)

# create new data frame with "Conference" and all possible 
# pair combinations of participants ("Participant 1", "Participant 2")
df2 <- rbindlist(
  lapply(subs, 
     function(sub) as.data.frame(cbind(
       as.character(sub$Conference[1]), 
       t(combn(sub$Participant,2))
       ))
  )
)

# Set the column names
setnames(df2, c("Conference", "P1", "P2"))

# store the new data frame to a csv-file
write.csv(df2, "Conference-Pairs.csv")
```

---

The Result then looks like this

```
                 Conference    P1    P2
1:       UN Conference 1945  John  Jack
2:       UN Conference 1945  John Jamie
3:       UN Conference 1945  John Pablo
4:       UN Conference 1945  Jack Jamie
5:       UN Conference 1945  Jack Pablo
6:       UN Conference 1945 Jamie Pablo
7: UN Conference Kyoto 1997   Ben Katie
8: UN Conference Kyoto 1997   Ben Julie
9: UN Conference Kyoto 1997 Katie Julie
```

Comment: To the downvote: Would you mind telling what caused the downvote? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry! Instead of voting up I voted down!!!! I am trying to reverse it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Pressing the up arrow should do it.